# Get all reference from slnFilePath

Tags: c#, winforms

is there a way i can get all active reference(dll) of a solution with use of slnPath ?
I've already found some solution but it just gets the reference of the project your coding(assembly), not the other project ...

updated:

> reference that can be found on csproj .

Comment: Do you want to skip the references that are `included` but not actually `used`? For example, `System.Xml.Linq` is included in VS 2010 C# project template but you may not need it?

Comment: @kennyzx if that dll was not installed locally then it will skip

Answer (score 0):

When you get the reference of the project of your assembly, then you can use `GetReferencedAssemblies` method in assembly object get its references. And you maybe need to avoid the duplicates.